# I created an App for Iphone, but i dont want to publish for everybody

Tags: iphone, app-store, publishing

How can i publish an app at app store, that only a few people (my clients) could download. Or is there another way to install it direct to their iPhone? Force them to jailbreak its not an option. 
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you are looking for the [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/), which costs $299 per year. It allows you to distribute iOS apps to employees (or clients in your case).

Answer (score 1):

You can use AdHoc, you need your client UDID devices, check this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use ad-hoc deployment or the iOS Developer Enterprise Program as others have mentioned, but on top of that you will probably find that tools such as [TestFlight](http://www.testflightapp.com/) will make the job of getting hold of UDIDs and pushing updates significantly easier to manage.